# How can I execute a script prior to the CMake step using Visual Studio Code's CMake Tools extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake

My use case: I want to execute a script setting up a virtual Python environment prior to any configure or build step. While I can simply source this script before calling CMake on the command line, I want to be able to do the same within the CMake Tools extension without having to adapt the `CMakeLists.txt` files.

The extension has the `cmake.environment`, `cmake.buildEnvironment` and `cmake.configureEnvironment` [settings](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/develop/docs/cmake-settings.md). But I don't want to manually reverse-engineer the script nor maintain the list of possibly changing environment variables. I simply want to execute the script and have CMake run in the sourced context.

Comment: use a compound task https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks

Comment: @rioV8 is it possible to mix manual tasks with tasks offered by extensions? In other words: How can I add a "task hook" to pre-defined tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Have the `cmake.cmakePath` point to a script that sources the original script (or calls whatever is wanted) then calls the actual CMake executable (along with forwarding all passed parameters).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
source /home/user/the_script_you_want_to_source # or whatever other script you want to have executed
/usr/local/bin/cmake "$@"                       # don't forget to forward the passed parameters
```

Note that it may be required to `chmod +x` the pointed-to script.

Comment: it doesn't work for me.
When I define the cmake.cmakePath to point on the full path of the very simple bash script with 2 lines: the 1st is 'echo "something"', and the 2nd is invoking of cmake, the VSCode shows the error:
"Bad CMake executable: "/home/path-to/script.sh". Check to make sure it is installed or the value of the "cmake.cmakePath" setting contains the correct path"
I understand this as impossibility to define cmake.cmakePath pointing to the bash script, and NOT on CMake executable !
So - how can I define script running before CMake and passing him parameters ?

Comment: @ZviDan I could reproduce the problem and I narrowed down to two possible causes causing this error message: 1) As mentioned in the original post, if the executable flag is missing. 2) If the original cmake is located elsewhere (e.g. `/usr/bin/cmake` instead of `/usr/local/bin/cmake`). In the latter case just adapt the path (which you can find out with `which cmake`) in the script.

Comment: @Ronald Sarrazin ,   
Finally I've added to "tasks.json" the following task:
"tasks": [
  {
            "label": "build",
            "type": "shell",
             "command": "./vscode_build.sh",
             "group": {
                "kind": "build",
                "isDefault": true
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$gcc"
        }
]
All preparations and subsequent CMake invoikng are located in the vscode_build.sh, and it works as expected !